# Full-text Search functionality in Spring Boot microservices based application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, lucene, microservices, hibernate-search

We have a microservice-based application which is developed in Spring Boot. Let us assume there are 3 microservices A, B, and C. The front-end is written using Angular and the backend comprises MySQL database and Hibernate for ORM. We are required to implement a full-text search functionality that will have a search box on the UI where the user can enter the text of his choice. The search must be able to return data from databases from all the 3 microservices. I am facing difficulty in finalizing the search technology for the same. Some of the technologies I have in my purview are

1. Hibernate Search
2. Apache Solr
3. ElasticSearch

Which is the best technology for this problem? If possible, are there any examples of the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hibernate search](https://hibernate.org/search/) looks to be depending on internal search solution for it to be providing full text search which could be either plain Apache Lucene or Elasticsearch. I'm not sure but its Elasticsearch integration if its already matured as [version 6.0](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/) is still in development stage.

The older/stable version of [Hibernate search i.e. 5.11](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.11/) supports Elasticsearch 2.0 to 5.6.

But looking at your queries, it depends on what you uses case you have. Perhaps below points would help you.

- What is the size of the data you have and what is the expected growth rate of your documents/data.
- What would be your write vs read rates for this application?
- What type of search use-cases you have? What features of search are you looking for? for e.g. Autocomplete, autosuggestion, highlighting, faceted-search
- Are you looking for a distributed search or do you have a limitation in using hardware?
- Is there a requirement to support search in multiple-languages?
- Is that only text search would suffice or would you also be doing analysis on the search logs or click-view data in the future?
- What options do you have when it comes to ingesting documents into your search engine. If its Elasticsearch you can easily make use of Beats or Logstash. Or you can simply dump raw data into ES, and then make use of a combination of [Ingest API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-apis.html) to do pre-processing/enrichment/filtering and then again push the processed data in different index in Elasticsearch.

Both Solr and Elasticsearch are great technologies but if you have to use one of them, I would strongly suggest in using [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch) because it would help you in all of the above queries, much more powerful distributed model, it has it own amazing DSL which is very mature and easy to use, has excellent administrative tools/API for data managment,  It is extremely fast and easy to set up. Not to mention their aggregation queries which helps you get analytical information about the documents you'd have ingested.

You would also have the luxury of setting up your own dashboard via [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/introduction.html) which would help you quickly create some great visualizers.

Plus point is it is completely **RESTful** by nature, so that means it makes your life easier when it comes to deployment of your applications. I'd suggest you to start from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/elasticsearch-intro.html) and spend sometime in understanding the technology.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**For fulltext search Elasticsearch and Apache Solr are the best choices from the given selection.**

However, I strongly disagree that Elasticsearch is better than Solr or other way around without knowing more info about your business case. Both technologies will perform equally for the given problem since they are both build upon Apache Lucene search engine.

They both offer great REST CLients.

[Here](https://github.com/tadijam64/search-engines-comparison) you can check out example implementation of both - Apache Solr and Elasticsearch in the same project in Java. You can also check what are the differences and which one do you prefer.

Also, there are six write-ups on how to use Apache Solr and Elasticsearch written [here](https://github.com/tadijam64/search-engines-comparison/wiki). Last chapter is about research which shows that both engines are almost equal and have differences only in very specific business cases. Both have many supporting tools as well.